# I'm implementing a deque using singly linked list in Java. My addLast() is not working

Tags: java, linked-list, stack, queue, deque

I'm implementing a deque using singly linked list in Java. My `addFirst()` function is working fine, but `addLast()` is not working.

Whenever I call `addLast()`, I got the following error message:

> java.lang.NullPointerException

[image: This is my function implementations]

Comment: What's the full stacktrace that's included with the `NullPointerException`? Your error console will tell you which line the exception is thrown on, and everything that was called up on to that point? Also, please post code as text, rather than as a screenshot, when asking questions.

Comment: Don't post your code as an image, post the code!

Comment: Where is the code that invokes addLast?

Comment: The error message from the console shows that old_last.next is null. Then I don't know how to modify this function so that it will successfully append an item to the back of a deque.

Comment: Please add invoke addLast method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving your Node class a constructor will help to keep your code short and DRY:

```
private class Node {
  Item item;
  Node next;
  private Node(Item item, Node next) {
    if (item == null) throw new NullPointerException();
// 'this' refers to the created instance and helps distinguish the field from the param
    this.item = item;  
    this.next = next;
  }
}

public void addFirst(Item item) {
  // creates a new Node before first so to speak and then repoints first to this node 
  first = new Node(item, first);   
  if (num_elements==0) last = first;
  num_elements++;
}

public void addLast(Item item) {
  if (num_elements == 0) {  
    // this will deal with the case (last==null) which causes the NPE
    addFirst(item);
    return;
  }
  last.next = new Node(item, null);
  last = last.next;
  num_elements++;
}
```

That aside, a singly linked list is not the ideal data structure for a deque. While adding is `O(1)` on both ends, removing from the back would be `O(N)`!

Comment: It works!! Thank you so much. But I am pretty new to Java so I don't really understand how it works. For example, I am confused about the class constructor, especially the keyword "this" in this context. Also, for the addFirst() function, why you just do first = new Node(item, first) instead of first.next = new Node(item, first)?

Comment: I added some comments to illuminate these points. `first.next = new Node(item, first)` would create a circular link structure, no. `first` refers to the the new Node and the new Node refers to first. Also, `first` might be null here, so this could fail.

Comment: Thank you so much!! Also, can you help me out on another Java Comparator question? I've been stuck on this for a really long time!    Thanks!              http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40622793/having-trouble-implementing-a-nested-class-comparator

Answer (score 2):

Your last is `null` at first.

When you assign it to `old_last`, `old_last` is null too.

So when you call `old_last.next`, `NPE` will throw.

Comment: Yes that's exactly the problem. Then do you know how to fix it? I know that you can implement a queue with a singly linked list, and the code to implement addLast() for a queue is exactly the same as mine. Then why the same implementations work for a queue but not for deque?

Comment: Check http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/56361/generic-deque-implementation on how to implement deque.