# Having trouble implementing a nested class comparator

Tags: java, algorithm, class, comparator, comparable

I'm implementing a Point class and trying to use a nested class to implement a comparator, which will compare based on the slope of two points. I'm having trouble implementing such comparator and don't understand how to use it in my main() function.

This is the error message I got when I try to compile it:

```
Point.java:20: error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
       if (Point.this.slopeTo(pt1) > Point.this.slopeTo(pt2)) {
                ^
Point.java:20: error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
       if (Point.this.slopeTo(pt1) > Point.this.slopeTo(pt2)) {
                                          ^
Point.java:22: error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
       } else if (Point.this.slopeTo(pt1) < Point.this.slopeTo(pt2)) {
                       ^
Point.java:22: error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
       } else if (Point.this.slopeTo(pt1) < Point.this.slopeTo(pt2)) {
                                                 ^
4 errors
```

The following are my codes:

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.lang.Comparable;
import java.util.Arrays;
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdDraw;
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdOut;


public class Point implements Comparable<Point> {
    private final int x;
    private final int y;

    // constructs the point (x, y)
    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    private static class bySlope implements Comparator<Point> {
        public int compare(Point pt1, Point pt2) {
            if (Point.this.slopeTo(pt1) > Point.this.slopeTo(pt2)) {
                return 1;
            } else if (Point.this.slopeTo(pt1) < Point.this.slopeTo(pt2)) {
                return -1;
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }

    // draws this point
    public void draw() {
        StdDraw.point(x, y);
    }

    // draws the line segment from this point to that point
    public void drawTo(Point that) {
        StdDraw.line(this.x, this.y, that.x, that.y);
    }

    // string representatio
    public String toString() {
        return "(" + x + ", " + y + ")";
    }

    // compare two points by y-coordinates, breaking ties by x-coordinates
    public int compareTo(Point that) {
        if (this.y > that.y) {
            return 1;
        } else if (this.y < that.y) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            if (this.x > that.x) {
                return 1;
            } else if (this.x < that.x) {
                return -1;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }

    // the slope between this point and that point
    public double slopeTo(Point that) {
        double lineSlope;
        // horizontal line
        if (that.y == this.y && that.x != this.x) {
            lineSlope = (1.0 - 1.0) / 1.0;
        } else if (that.y != this.y && that.x == this.x) {
            lineSlope = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
        } else if (that.y == this.y && that.x == this.x) {
            lineSlope = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
        } else {
            lineSlope = (that.y - this.y) / (that.x - this.x);
        }
        return lineSlope;
    }

    // compare two points by slopes they make with this point
    public Comparator<Point> slopeOrder() {
        return new bySlope();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Point[] myPoints = new Point[3];

        myPoints[0] = new Point(1,2);
        myPoints[1] = new Point(3,4);
        myPoints[2] = new Point(7,8);

        Arrays.sort(myPoints, new Point.bySlope());

        for (int i = 0; i < myPoints.length; i++) {
            StdOut.println(myPoints[i].toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove `static` from `bySlope`.

Comment: I tried that. Then I got the following error:                                        Point.java:89: error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
     Arrays.sort(myPoints, new Point.bySlope());
                           ^
1 error

Comment: Then you're fixing it in a backwards. The solution is not to make it static, but to not reference it in a static way.

Comment: `Point.this` ??

Comment: I'm new to Java so I don't really understand when I should use static and when I shouldn't use it. Then do you have any suggestion as to how to fix it?

Comment: What are you trying to do by including `Point.this`, `pt1` and `pt2` in a single comparison?

Comment: The reason I use Point.this is that I'm trying to access slopeTo(). Since the comparator is a nested class, then I assume "this" would just refer to the current instance of the comparator class.

Comment: slopeTo would return the slope of two points. I'm trying to compare the slope of two lines by calling slopeTo. But I'm not sure if "Point.this" is the correct syntax.

Comment: Your class is implementing `Comparable` and also using`Comparator`. Seems like you are not sure what exactly you need.

Comment: For Comparable, I'm trying to compare two points by the values of their coordinates. For Comparator, I'm trying to compare two points by the values of slope.

Comment: You're not comparing two lines, you're using one point to compare two others. At least that's what your code says.

Comment: Yes. There are actually three points involved in this case. pt1 and pt2 are two external points and "Point.this" is meant to be the reference point. I need to calculate the slope of pt1 and "Point.this", as well as the slope of pt2 and "Point.this", then I want to compare these two slopes.

Comment: But your `main()` method doesn't have any shared point of comparison.

Comment: Yeah I think there is something wrong with my main() as well. I just don't understand how to go about implementing a Comparator using a nested class in this case. Do you have any suggestion? I'm completely lost.

Comment: We can't help without understanding what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should provide inner class instance into Arrays.sort to compare points from view of parent class instance. To do it you should not create new instance in main() function, but get it from Point instance.

So, in main function you should use something like this:

```
Point pivot;
... // set up pivot point here
Arrays.sort(myPoints, pivot.slopeOrder());
```

Also you should remove "static" from nested class definition so it becomes inner class, that can actually access its parent members:

```
private class bySlope implements Comparator<Point> {
```

Comment: OMG! Thank you so much you save my life! One last question: What is the difference by making the nested class definition "non-static"? I guess I'm really confused about the difference between static and non-static in this context.

Comment: "nested" class is static and it can not access parent non-static members directly, "inner" class is non-static and can access non-static parent class members, essentially inner class instance holds reference to parent class instance in <ParentClass>.this, but you can use member variables from parent class without it. For example, "if (slopeTo(pt1) > slopeTo(pt2))" in your comparator should work well.